# Getting the value from a dynamic NumericUpDown by Sender c#

Tags: c#, dynamic, sender, numericupdown, eventargs

I've ran into quite an annoying problem.

I've got these global variables (for keeping the name etc)

```
List<object> NumeriekVakken = new List<object>();
        List<decimal> bedragenLijst = new List<decimal>();
        List<string> namenlijstVanNumericFields = new List<string>();
        List<string> namenLijst = new List<string>();
```

Afterwards I have a function that makes NumericUpDowns, depending on the number of records in the db.
The function looks like this:

```
private void InitializeComponentControlArrayKnoppenTextboxenEnLabels()
        {

    foreach (DataRow dr in blCategorie.getAlleCategorieenMetLimieten())
            {
        double limiet = (double) dr.Field<double>("maximumBedrag");
                NumericUpDown numeriekVak = new NumericUpDown();
                numeriekVak.Name = "numeriekvak" + i;
                numeriekVak.Width = 100;
                numeriekVak.Maximum = 30000;
                numeriekVak.Minimum = 0;
                numeriekVak.Increment = 10;
                numeriekVak.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(limiet);
                numeriekVak.Location = new Point(250, beginhoogte + verhogenMet);
                this.Controls.Add(numeriekVak);

        NumeriekVakken.Add(numeriekVak);
                bedragenLijst.Add(numeriekVak.Value);
                namenlijstVanNumericFields.Add(numeriekVak.Name);
                namenLijst.Add(categorie);

        //to make unique names for my Numerics etc.
        i++;
                counter++;

                //click event aanmaken
                button.Click += new EventHandler(buttonWijzig_Click);
            }
}
```

And in the ending I want to update a record whenever the numericUpDown is changed by the user (by clicking on the numericupdown or changing the numbers)

```
private void buttonWijzig_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button knop = (Button)sender;
            NumericUpDown numeriekvak = (NumericUpDown)sender;

            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
            {
                if (knop.Name == "knop" + i)
                {
                    int id = i, maximumBedrag = 0;

                    if (namenlijstVanNumericFields[i] == "numeriekvak" + i)
                    {
                        // update limit
                        DBManager.LimietRow limiet = new DBManager.LimietDataTable().NewLimietRow();
                        maximumBedrag = Convert.ToInt32(numeriekvak.Value);
                        blLimiet.updateLimiet(id, maximumBedrag);
                    }

                    labelBevestigingLimiet.Text = "Limiet " + namenLijst[i].ToString() + " is succesvol gewijzigd naar " + maximumBedrag + "€";

                    //stopping of loop if right button is found.
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

But evertime I run this I get the same problem.. 
"Can't convert the object from the type System.Windows.Forms.Button to the type
System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown"

How can I fix this and update the record depending on the new number thats filled in on the NumericUpDown? I can't get this working, I've got a feeling it has to do with the sender thats not working good..

Thanks for all the help!
Yenthe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have assigned the event handler `buttonWijzig_Click` to a control button.
This control is not defined anywhere in your code above. 
(By the way, you assign the method at the same control for every loop)

I think you want to assign your event handler to every NumericUpDown created in the loop as

```
numeriekVak.Click += new EventHandler(buttonWijzig_Click);
```

Of course the event handler now receives a NumericUpDown control in the sender argument and not a button, so the code of the event handler should be changed accordingly

```
private void buttonWijzig_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     NumericUpDown numeriekvak = (NumericUpDown)sender;
     int id = 0, maximumBedrag = 0;

     // The ID could be extracted from the control name starting at 11 position
     id = Convert.ToInt32(numeriekvak.Name.Substring(11));

     // update limit
     DBManager.LimietRow limiet = new DBManager.LimietDataTable().NewLimietRow();
     maximumBedrag = Convert.ToInt32(numeriekvak.Value);
     blLimiet.updateLimiet(id, maximumBedrag);

     // The control name is already available, no need to use the list to retrieve it
     labelBevestigingLimiet.Text = "Limiet " + numeriekVak.Name + " is succesvol gewijzigd naar " + maximumBedrag + "€";

}
```

However, let me say that for your stated purpose:

> And in the ending I want to update a record whenever the numericUpDown
>   is changed by the user (by clicking on the numericupdown or changing
>   the numbers)

it is better to use the `ValueChanged` event because this will be fired also when the user changes the value manually and not with up/down buttons. The code above will fit as well for the [ValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.valuechanged%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event

**EDIT**
Based on your comment below then the assignment of the event handler goes back to the button (there is no code to create the button, so I have assumed that you have followed the same naming convention as for yours NumericUpDown), but insted of using a list to keep track of your NumericUpDown I would use a `Dictionary<int, NumericUpDown>` where the integer is the id needed to retrieve the corresponding NumericUpDown from the button name.

In declaration change

```
Dictionary<int, NumericUpDown> NumeriekVakken = new Dictionary<int, NumericUpDown> ();
```

In Initialization inside `InitializeComponentControlArrayKnoppenTextboxenEnLabels` change

```
namenlijstVanNumericFields.Add(i, numeriekVak);
```

In button click code

```
private void buttonWijzig_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Button knop = sender as Button;
     int id = 0, maximumBedrag = 0;

     // The ID could be extracted from the control name starting at 4th position
     id = Convert.ToInt32(knop.Name.Substring(4));

     // The ID is the key to find the corresponding NUmericUpDown in the dictionary
     NumericUpDown numeriekvak = NumeriekVakken[id];

     // update limit
     DBManager.LimietRow limiet = new DBManager.LimietDataTable().NewLimietRow();
     maximumBedrag = Convert.ToInt32(numeriekvak.Value);
     blLimiet.updateLimiet(id, maximumBedrag);

     // The control name is already available, no need to use the list to retrieve it
     labelBevestigingLimiet.Text = "Limiet " + numeriekVak.Name + " is succesvol gewijzigd naar " + maximumBedrag + "€";

}
```

Comment: Woha this does what I want for 95%+! But how could I only trigger this when a button is clicked? The thing is I'd want it to update when the correct BUTTON is clicked, but not the NumericUpDown. That would save numerous of updates (which are a bit unneedded in my idea?)
Thank you for this already Steve! :)

Comment: So you have ONE button named (for example) Save and you want to update the limits of all of your NumericUpDown when your press this button?

Comment: In fact I have eight buttons and eight numericUpDowns, with all different values.
And I want it to only update the corresponding NumericUpDown that matches to the clicked button!

Comment: OK then I assume that your buttons have the same naming convetion of the NumericUpDown (I.E. "knop1" is related to "numeriekvak1"?). I need to ask because your code doesn't show how do you create dinamucally these buttons

Comment: Just so its easy for you to follow:
int id = (int)dr.Field<int>("id");
Button button = new Button();
button.Name = "knop" + i;
                button.Width = 30;
                button.Height = 30;
                button.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.OKIcoon;
button.Text = Convert.ToString(id);
button.Location = new Point(380, (beginhoogte + verhogenMet) - 4);
this.Controls.Add(button);
So yeah, the buttons and the numericUpDowns match eachother with 1,2,3,4,5, ... and are related :)

Comment: You need to be sure that the ID read from the database has the same value used for the button and numeriupdown name. If it is the same the code will work. If is not the same you could still use the variable i to find the numerics but you need to extract the ID from the button text to use for your database updates

Comment: I'm gonna count the answer as correct. Your code was 100% correct, I only had another minor error in my SQL query (in the BL layer)
Thank you Steve :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: since you event is fired by a button, you cannot convert the sender to numeric updown.

I see you have only one `button` and it's not declared in you code.
I assume it's in the form, right???

> Did you mean to add that click event many times to a single button???
>
> Or did you mean to add events `to each` NumericUpDown???

If it's the second option, you should add the click event to each numeric updown.
See this line in your code.

```
//click event aanmaken
button.Click += new EventHandler(buttonWijzig_Click);
```

Comment: ^The thing is that you can't use the button.Click since you can't sender a button to a NumericUpDown, as Steve explained me up there!
So this won't work, sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.RowIndex >= 0) {
            DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            iD_supplierNumericUpDown.Value = row.Cells["ID"].Selected(); // this is the problem
            nSupplierTextBox.Text = row.Cells["NSupplier"].Value.ToString();
            e_mailTextBox.Text = row.Cells["E_mailTextBox"].Value.ToString();
            phoneTextBox.Text = row.Cells["Phone"].Value.ToString();
        }
```